# NullPointerException using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to do what should be a simple post to a website and receive a response but I am having problems with implementing `AsyncTask` to supply the required secondary stream. Currently I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Any ideas what's causing this?

Logcat:

```
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at ca.waddlesoft.smpclient_android.MainActivity$SmpProcessor.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:50)
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at ca.waddlesoft.smpclient_android.MainActivity$SmpProcessor.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
07-18 11:34:14.829: E/AndroidRuntime(8354):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Code:

```
package ca.waddlesoft.smpclient_android;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import ca.waddlesoft.smpclient_android.R;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv;
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SmpProcessor task = new SmpProcessor();
        task.execute();
    }

    private class SmpProcessor extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids){
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://secure.g4apps.com");
            String app="A1";
            String data = "E1,E1,AT333AT333,9055627513,2012-02-02 02:02:02,2012-02-02 02:02:02,-454545.343434,434343.232323,A334A334A334A443X,1000000,3434";
            byte [] databyte=data.getBytes();
            String out = SmpClass.smpCall(url,app,data);
            //  String out = new String(smpresponse);
            return out;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        tv.setText(result);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Accept answer which solved ur prob...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 mistakes:

- You declare your `textView` locally + in your class. Just declare it in
  your class.
- You initialize your `textView` before calling `setContentView`

Try this:

```
package ca.waddlesoft.smpclient_android;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import ca.waddlesoft.smpclient_android.R;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

        SmpProcessor task = new SmpProcessor();
        task.execute();
    }

  private class SmpProcessor extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids){
                URL url = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL("http://secure.g4apps.com");
                    String app="A1";
                    String data = "E1,E1,AT333AT333,9055627513,2012-02-02 02:02:02,2012-02-02 02:02:02,-454545.343434,434343.232323,A334A334A334A443X,1000000,3434";
//                  byte [] databyte=data.getBytes();
                    String out = SmpClass.smpCall(url,app,data);
//                  String out = new String(smpresponse);
                    return out;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    tv.setText(result);
            }
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this line:

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
```

after this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: That won't help him, since the field tv which he is referring to will still be null.

Comment: @edem You're right. But I guess he'll still need to do the step in my answer. No?

Answer (score 1):

You have a *local* `tv` variable which holds your `TextView`. Since you do not put a reference into your `tv` field it will be null hence the `NullPointerException`.

You can solve this problem by simply deleting your declaration of the local variable `tv`:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);            
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        SmpProcessor task = new SmpProcessor();
        task.execute();
    }
```

You also have to move the

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

line before you manipulate `View`s or the android framework will complain.

If confused you can read about variable scope here: [Java variable scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm).

Comment: Check the code I included. You have to set the content view before finding your TextView. It will return null if you don't set the content view before.

Comment: So it's basically "Raining nulls" until you correct the above.

Answer (score 0):

You declare another `tv`  locally.
So the result of `findViewById` is stored in the *local* variable `tv`, instead of the *field* `tv` which remains `null`.
Remove `TextView tv;` from your `onCreate` method.
As @Dheeraj and @you786 pointed out before me, you should also call `setContentView(...)`  before trying to get the handle to the `TextView`.
After that, it should work.